# Unable to install Go packages in Macbook with M1 chip

Tags: go, delve

When I ran the command "go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv" in the delve folder, after downloading go-delve in my go path, the terminal showed the following result:
"go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv: mkdir /Desktop: read-only file system"
[Terminal result put here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q9LK.png)

When I googled the same, I came across a website(https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-error-when-run-mkdir-command-on-macos/) which requires me to disable System Integrity Protection on my MacBook and it asks me to hold the option key or command + R immediately after Mac chimes in reboot after starting the MacBook, until I see a boot in a "console/terminal" mode.. But nothing happened when I tried doing that.
I am not knowing what to do. Please guide me through the right way to install dlv and other packages of go successfully on my Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you use the right go version (1.16 or later, arm64)

```sh
$ go version
go version go1.17.1 darwin/arm64
```

2. make sure the `env` is right by this command

```sh
$ go env
```

check `GOROOT` `GOPATH` `GOARCH` `GOBIN`

2. try to install it directly

```sh
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
```

your error occurs because you have no permission of `/Desktop`, and i'm sure install dlv don't need something like this, it will install to `~/go/bin`